# How do you convert a cursor to CTE? T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, optimization

In an effort to clarify I have added more information and removed the "simplified" code.

I have table with datetime punch information.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AT_Punches](
    [PunchID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Facility] [char](3) NULL,
    [person_code] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [AltJob] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [INOUT] [char](3) NULL,
    [edit_user] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [edit_datetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [create_datetime] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__AT_Punch] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PunchID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
-- TEST DATA
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AT_Punches] ([Facility],[person_code],[TimeStamp],[AltJob],[INOUT],[edit_user],[edit_datetime],[create_datetime])
                        VALUES ('ABC','JDOE','2020-07-06 15:03:48.960','RN','In','tester',GETDATE(),GETDATE())
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AT_Punches] ([Facility],[person_code],[TimeStamp],[AltJob],[INOUT],[edit_user],[edit_datetime],[create_datetime])
                        VALUES ('ABC','JDOE','2020-07-07 03:43:38.000','RN','Out','tester',GETDATE(),GETDATE())
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AT_Punches] ([Facility],[person_code],[TimeStamp],[AltJob],[INOUT],[edit_user],[edit_datetime],[create_datetime])
                        VALUES ('XYZ','KLO','2020-07-07 06:18:08.000','RN','In','tester',GETDATE(),GETDATE())
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AT_Punches] ([Facility],[person_code],[TimeStamp],[AltJob],[INOUT],[edit_user],[edit_datetime],[create_datetime])
                        VALUES ('XYZ','JSMITH','2020-07-07 15:01:40.000','RN','In','tester',GETDATE(),GETDATE())
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AT_Punches] ([Facility],[person_code],[TimeStamp],[AltJob],[INOUT],[edit_user],[edit_datetime],[create_datetime])
                        VALUES ('XYZ','JSMITH','2020-07-08 03:43:38.000','RN','Out','tester',GETDATE(),GETDATE())
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AT_Punches] ([Facility],[person_code],[TimeStamp],[AltJob],[INOUT],[edit_user],[edit_datetime],[create_datetime])
                        VALUES ('XYZ','ABARR','2020-07-08 04:12:33.000','RN','In','tester',GETDATE(),GETDATE())
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AT_Punches] ([Facility],[person_code],[TimeStamp],[AltJob],[INOUT],[edit_user],[edit_datetime],[create_datetime])
                        VALUES ('XYZ','ABARR','2020-07-08 07:19:22.000','RN','Out','tester',GETDATE(),GETDATE())
```

I need to turn those records into a report that pairs up punches while making note of the "missing" punches.  It would look something like this.

```
Facility Person              Vendor Job In               Out              Hours 
ABC      Jane Doe (JDOE)     12345  RN  7/6/2020 3:00 PM 7/7/2020 3:45 AM 12.75 
XYZ      Kim Lo (KLO)        34567  RN  7/7/2020 6:15 AM *** MISSING ***  0.00 
XYZ      Jon Smith (JSMITH)  34567  RN  7/7/2020 3:00 PM 7/8/2020 3:45 AM 12.75 
XYZ      Angela Barr (ABARR) 34567  RN  7/8/2020 4:15 AM 7/8/2020 7:15 AM 3.00
```

I am currently using a cursor in an sp to work this out but it takes too long to run.  To process 700ish records takes about 45 seconds.  I feel it be done faster.  Here is that sp.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Missing_Punch_Formatter]
@StartDate date, @EndDate date, @faccode varchar(4), @userID varchar(20)
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
DECLARE @boolIN   BIT

DECLARE @PunchesCursor AS CURSOR

DECLARE @strLastStamp   DATETIME
DECLARE @strLastOut   VARCHAR (25)
DECLARE @strLastPerson   VARCHAR (12)

DECLARE @strLastRecNo   INT
DECLARE @counter   INT

DECLARE @facility   CHAR (3)
DECLARE @vendorid   VARCHAR (8)
DECLARE @person_code   VARCHAR (12)
DECLARE @altjob   VARCHAR (12)
DECLARE @Inout   CHAR (3)
DECLARE @timestamp   DATETIME
DECLARE @InPunch   VARCHAR (25)
DECLARE @OutPunch   VARCHAR (25)
DECLARE @is_round  char(1)

BEGIN
   /********************* delete temp work table data *********************/

   DELETE FROM atrax.dbo.at_punchwork
    WHERE userid = @userid AND faccode = @faccode;

   /********************* reformat and calc punches *********************/
   SET @PunchesCursor =
          CURSOR FOR
             SELECT facility,
                    vendorid,
                    person_code,
                    altjob,
                    Inout,
                    timestamp,
                    InPunch,
                    OutPunch, is_round
               FROM (SELECT p.facility,
                            a.vendorid,
                            p.person_code,
                            p.altjob,
                            p.timestamp,
                            p.INOUT,
                            isnull (format (p.timestamp, 'g'), '****')
                               AS InPunch,
                            '****' AS OutPunch, 'Y' as is_round
                       FROM atrax.dbo.AT_Punches p
                            JOIN atrax.dbo.AT_person e
                               ON     p.Facility = e.Facility
                                  AND p.person_code = e.Person_code
                            JOIN atrax.dbo.AT_agency a
                               ON e.VendorID = a.VendorID
                      WHERE p.INOUT = 'In'
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT p.facility,
                            a.vendorid,
                            p.person_code,
                            p.altjob,
                            p.timestamp,
                            p.INOUT,
                            '****' AS InPunch,
                            isnull (format (timestamp, 'g'), '****')
                               AS OutPunch, 'Y' as is_round
                       FROM atrax.dbo.AT_Punches p
                            JOIN atrax.dbo.AT_person e
                               ON     p.Facility = e.Facility
                                  AND p.person_code = e.Person_code
                            JOIN atrax.dbo.AT_agency a
                               ON e.VendorID = a.VendorID
                      WHERE p.INOUT = 'Out') AS t
              WHERE     timestamp >= @startdate
                    AND timestamp <= dateadd(DD,1,@enddate)
                    AND facility = @faccode
             ORDER BY facility,
                      VendorID,
                      person_code,
                      timestamp;

   SET @strLastPerson = '';
   SET @strLastStamp = '';
   SET @strLastOut = '';

   SET @boolIN = 0;                                              

   SET @strLastRecNo = 0;
   SET @counter = 0;
   
-- Open PUNCHES for Processing 
   
   OPEN @PunchesCursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM @PunchesCursor
        INTO @facility,
             @vendorid,
             @person_code,
             @altjob,
             @Inout,
             @timestamp,
             @InPunch,
             @OutPunch,
             @is_round

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      SET @counter += 1;                                 -- Record # = counter

      -- start new record for new person if not first record in
      IF @person_code <> @strLastPerson AND @counter <> 1
         BEGIN
            -- if record already pending finish last record
            IF @boolIN = 1
               BEGIN
                  -- if record has been started then finish with it, save out data from in punch (missing)
                  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

                  UPDATE atrax.dbo.at_punchwork
                     SET timestampout = @strLastStamp, OutPunch = @strLastOut
                   WHERE     recno = @strLastRecNo
                         AND userid = @userid
                         AND faccode = @faccode;

                  COMMIT;
                  -- Reset Vars
                  SET @boolIN = 0                                      --False

                  SET @strLastStamp = ''
                  SET @strLastOut = ''
               END
         END                                                 -- end new person

      IF @Inout = 'In'
         BEGIN
            -- Process the in record
            IF @boolIN = 1
               BEGIN
                  -- if record has been started then finish with it, save out data from in punch (missing)
                  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

                  UPDATE atrax.dbo.at_punchwork
                     SET timestampout = @strLastStamp, OutPunch = @strLastOut
                   WHERE     recno = @strLastRecNo
                         AND userid = @userid
                         AND faccode = @faccode;

                  COMMIT;

                  SET @boolIN = 0                                      --False

                  SET @strLastStamp = ''
                  SET @strLastOut = ''
               END                                                   -- boolin

            -- Start a new IN for current record
            SET @boolIN = 1                                             --true

            INSERT INTO atrax.dbo.at_punchwork (recno,
                                                faccode,
                                                vendorid,
                                                person_code,
                                                WorkedJob,
                                                timestamp,
                                                Inout,
                                                InPunch,
                                                userid,
                                                is_round)
            VALUES (@Counter,
                    @faccode,
                    @vendorid,
                    @person_code,
                    @Altjob,
                    @timestamp,
                    @Inout,
                    @inpunch,
                    @userid,
                    @is_round);


            -- save out data from this record
            SET @strLastStamp = @timestamp
            SET @strLastOut = @outpunch
         END
      ELSE                                                      -- INout = Out
         BEGIN
            -- process out record

            IF @boolIN = 1
               BEGIN
                  -- Record all ready started -- Add Out part from curr record
                  UPDATE atrax.dbo.at_punchwork
                     SET timestampout = @timestamp, OutPunch = @outpunch
                   WHERE     recno = @strLastRecNo
                         AND userid = @userid
                         AND faccode = @faccode;

                  SET @strLastStamp = ''
                  SET @strLastOut = ''

                  SET @boolIN = 0
               END
            ELSE
               BEGIN
                  -- add whole out Record (no in found).
                  INSERT INTO atrax.dbo.at_punchwork (recno,
                                                      faccode,
                                                      vendorid,
                                                      person_code,
                                                      WorkedJob,
                                                      timestamp,
                                                      Inout,
                                                      InPunch,
                                                      timestampout,
                                                      OutPunch,
                                                      userid, 
                                                      is_round)
                  VALUES (@counter,
                          @faccode,
                          @vendorid,
                          @person_code,
                          @Altjob,
                          @timestamp,
                          @inout,
                          @inpunch,
                          @timestamp,
                          @outpunch,
                          @userid,
                          @is_round);

                  SET @strLastStamp = ''
                  SET @strLastOut = ''

                  SET @boolIN = 0
               END                                                  -- bool IN
         END                                                          -- INOUT

      SET @strLastRecNo = @counter;
      SET @strLastPerson = @person_code;

      FETCH NEXT FROM @PunchesCursor
           INTO @facility,
                @vendorid,
                @person_code,
                @altjob,
                @Inout,
                @timestamp,
                @InPunch,
                @OutPunch,
                @is_round
   END                                                              --end loop
END
GO
```

Is there a faster way to do this kind of thing, maybe without a cursor?

Comment: how do you match IN and OUT?

Comment: @Nikita order by the punchDT for a user at a location.  In theory, the first record should be an "In" punch.  The next an "Out" punch.  It should alternate like that until a missing punch is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Revised answer, given clarifications in the question**

The question is basically, for a given combination of person_code and facility, when you sort the records in [timestamp] order, you want to make sure every row showing an inout value of 'in' is followed by 'out' and vice versa - and that the last row shows 'out'.

Here's the solution using `lead` - which is a T-SQL function to read data values from rows further down the resultset than the current row. We use this basically to check: is the next row for the same person-facility combination? If so, then does the INOUT value on the next row differ from this row? If so, then great. If not, then there's a problem. However, if the next row is for some different person-facility combination, then on the current row, is the INOUT value 'out'? If not, then they haven't clocked out yet.

```
select 
    *,
case
    when lead(Facility,1,'') over (order by person_code, Facility, [TimeStamp]) = Facility
        and lead(person_code,1,'') over (order by person_code, Facility, [TimeStamp]) = person_code
        and lead(INOUT,1,'') over (order by person_code, Facility, [TimeStamp]) = INOUT
        then 'boohoo - next row is the same'
    when lead(Facility,1,'') over (order by person_code, Facility, [TimeStamp]) = Facility
        and lead(person_code,1,'') over (order by person_code, Facility, [TimeStamp]) = person_code
        and lead(INOUT,1,'') over (order by person_code, Facility, [TimeStamp]) <> INOUT
        then 'hooray - next row is different'
    when 
        (
            lead(Facility,1,'') over (order by person_code, Facility, [TimeStamp]) <> Facility
            or lead(person_code,1,'') over (order by person_code, Facility, [TimeStamp]) <> person_code
        )
        and INOUT = 'In'
        then 'boohoo - Not clocked out yet...'
     else 'hooray - last row for this person-location - and they clocked out :)' end
from at_punches 
order by person_code, Facility, [TimeStamp];
```

**Initial answer**

(This answer was when I thought they simply needed to show any rows where there weren't a matching number of clock-outs per person. I'll leave the answer here although it's trivial).

Try the following.

```
select * from tblPunches
where
    (select count(1) from tblPunches p2 where p2.userID = tblPunches.userID and p2.punchType = 'IN')
<> (select count(1) from tblPunches p3 where p3.userID = tblPunches.userID and p2.punchType = 'OUT')
```

Seems to me - if there is an unequal number of "IN" and "OUT" punches for a given user, there's an issue, no?

The above contains no logic to ensure an "OUT" punch correlates to a specific "IN" punch - for example, being on the same day, being within 24 hours or whatever - but neither did your question seem to imply that requirement.

PS. As I wrote this answer you posted a clarification comment that you want to iterate through the rows based on a timestamp. The above will return *all* rows for a given user if that user has any mismatch between IN and OUT punches.

If you want to return *just* the row where IN occurs twice in a row, or OUT occurs twice in a row (when ordered by a timestamp), then [see my recent answer on a similar problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270582/comparing-running-total-with-group-by). I literally posted this five minutes ago and this approach will pull out just the single rows with issues for you.

Comment: I've already updated the answer - seems we are cross-posting! :D Follow the link for an approach that will return the result you want. (PS - the question wasn't really clear about that requirement initially).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I need to go tinker with it for a bit and learn how to apply it to my needs.  I'd like to make the CTE work but I haven't used that before.

Comment: You're welcome. I think your scenario is simpler because you just need to look back at the prior row - not keep a running total over many rows. If you can prepare SQL to create the table and populate it with reasonable data for your use cases, I think I can knock out the SQL pretty quickly ... and it will be simpler. Same principle though - use `lag`. Probably only one CTE and that's to `union` with a dummy, future-dated record so we can move off your last row of data onto the dummy row then read back one row.

Comment: Ok, give me a few to update the question with more details.

Comment: Took a little longer to get the test data than expected.

Comment: @WillG - give this a go - answer revised.

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to LEAD and LAG, I've put them to work now.